# Signed app to replace debug build

Tags: android, database, installation, apk

While developing an app, I've installed its debug version on a tablet to test it. The app has been storing data for a while in its database. The development has finished and I have created a signed apk. The problem is, when I tried to install over the debug version in my tablet, I was told "no go, different certificate/signature/password" or some such and was asked to uninstall the previous app. However, if I do that, I will lose the database and I prefer not to.

So. What are my options? Copy the DB to external storage and then copy it back to internal storage afterwards? Or is there some installation/certification jujitsu to be done here?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it myself but this should do the trick:

How to use adb `uninstall`

[**General Usage**]

overview: remove this app package from the device

usage: `adb uninstall package_name`

eg: `adb uninstall com.android.chrome`

[**Optional Parameters**]

`-k` means keep the data and cache directories

usage: `adb uninstall -k package_name`

eg: `adb uninstall -k com.android.chrome`

[**Return**]

If uninstallation succeeds, the return value is `Success`.Otherwise return `Failure`. It means package is not installed.

*-Source: http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-uninstall/how-to-use-adb-uninstall.html*